# How to select an element from a sub menu using Selenium Webdriver with Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have looked at many different examples and none seem to work for my situation. I am simply trying to select a clickable div element from a navigation menu that I open. I can easily select the nav menu, but when I select the item I get the error:

```
driver.find_element_by_text('My Repository').click()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_text'
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Python27\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(3)
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()


...

driver.find_element_by_class_name('navLaunchButton').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('My Repository').click() #Error happens here (submenu)
```

Can someone please assist?
Thanks in advance for any direction you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is quite informative: there is no such method as `find_element_by_text()`. There are [`find_element_by_link_text()` and `find_element_by_partial_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) which can be applied to link elements (e.g. `<a>link text</a>`), but if you want find `<div>` by its text content, you can try [search by XPath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='My Repository']")  # by exact text content
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'My Repository')]")  # by partial content
```